# Replace username with "your" in the "Delete comment" prompt

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

The phrasing in the "Delete comment" prompt seems awkward.

As Grant doesn't have permission to delete anyone *else's* comments, and could only be deleting Grant's (and doesn't regularly refer to himself in the third-person), this looks strange.

Can the prompt be changed to read:

> Are you sure you want to delete your comment?

Alternatively, with a [royal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we) twist:

> Are we sure we want to delete our comment?

App Version: 1.0.62

[image]

Comment: might be related to moderators and their privileges?

Comment: My vote is for "Is Grant Winney sure Grant Winney wants to delete Grant Winney's comment?"

Comment: what is the function to deleted the comment yourself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done.  This will be in the next build.

> [image]
>  
>  Er... maybe not that.

Comment: "deleted by `Grant Winney` May 12 at 23:12"